# How to Check box filter In Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter, django-template-filters

*I'm using Django as backend, Postgres SQL as DB, and HTML, CSS, and Javascript as frontend*. I am stuck in the filtering option, where the user selects `check` one brand and shows the selected brand list in the template. So basically like this:

[image]

I have multiple specifications for each category. Like Mobiles have:

1. Brand
2. RAM
3. ROM
   etc.

Till now, I have done list filtering but I want check-box filtering.

The Codes goes here:

**views.py**

```
def product(request, data=None):
    product = Product.objects.all()

    if data == None:
        proc = Product.objects.filter(category = 1)
    elif data == 'OnePlus' or data == 'boAt' or data == 'Redmi' or data == 'realme':
        proc = Product.objects.filter(category = 1).filter(brand = data) 

    return render(request, 'list/processor.html', {'product': product, 'proc':proc,})
```

**product.html**

```
<ul class="list-group">
                <a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url 'main:product' %}">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        All
                    </li>
                </a>
                <a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url 'main:productdata' 'OnePlus'%}">
                    <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                        OnePlus
                    </li>
                .......  
            </ul>
```

I have searched for `Django-Filter` but proper implementation of check-box filtering not there. How the **Checkbox filtering** will be done because this process takes too much time. Is there any easy way where all the particular columns get a filter, for ex. if brand name `LG` is repeated *more than one time* the query will filter those to one and append them to check-box filtering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your implementation of checkboxes being links, it makes most sense to do this filtering via get requests rather than URL parameters.

For example;

```
    def product(request):
        brand = request.GET.get('brand')

        if brand:
            product = Product.objects.filter(category=1).filter(brand=brand)
        else:
            product = Product.objects.filter(category=1)

        products = Product.objects.all() 
    
        return render(
            request, 'list/processor.html',
            {'products': products, 'product': product,}
        )
```

`product.html`

```
    <ul class="list-group">
                    <a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url 'main:product' %}">
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            All
                        </li>
                    </a>
                    <a style="text-decoration:none" href="{% url 'main:productdata' %}?brand=OnePlus">
                        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            OnePlus
                        </li>
                    .......  
                </ul>
```

To use checkboxes, you'd need a form to handle the input by the user;

```
<form action="{% url 'main:productdata' %}" method="get">
    <label for="oneplus">OnePlus: </label>
    <input id="oneplus" type="checkbox" name="oneplus">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

```
    def product(request):
        oneplus = request.GET.get('oneplus')

        if oneplus:
            product = Product.objects.filter(category=1).filter(brand__iexact=oneplus)
        else:
            product = Product.objects.filter(category=1)

        products = Product.objects.all() 
    
        return render(
            request, 'list/processor.html',
            {'products': products, 'product': product,}
        )
```

If I were you, I'd also do this using a django form to make rendering it easier. The form might look something like this;

```py
class BrandForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        brands = Product.objects.filter(category=1).values_list('brand', flat=True)
        for brand in brands:
            self.fields[f'{brand}'] = forms.BooleanField(label=f'{brand}')
```

In your view you then need to create an instance of the form and pass it in the context.

```py
        form = BrandForm()
        return render(
            request, 'list/processor.html',
            {'form': form, 'products': products, 'product': product}
        )
```

And then render the form;

```
<form action="{% url 'main:productdata' %}" method="get">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: Hello Sir, How will be the URLS look like mine is  `path('productdata/<slug:data>', views.product, name='productdata'),`. And how I will implement on checkboxes?

Comment: I have done URL Implementation and working absolutely fine. how will I go with checkboxes? Any HINT

Comment: To properly do checkboxes, you'd need to be rendering a form, not a list of links. And that form would have to use the `GET` method to submit. I'll update my answer with a quick example of how it might look.

Comment: The form one is seem to be easy and more meaningful

Comment: Hello @markwalker, Sir, the boolean field is not working as I set the `required = false` in the form and checked one brand then it is giving o/p nothing just refreshing the page. just like this `self.fields[f'{brand}'] = forms.BooleanField(label=f'{brand}', required=False)`

Comment: @santoshChauhan Ok, so what does `request.GET` contain after submission of the form? You'll need to debug it

Comment: while running the code. and then check the checkbox and press OK, I get this in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/product/?Samsung=on` and in my vs code console. `[23/Jun/2021 08:58:50] "GET /product/?Samsung=on HTTP/1.1" 200 129561`

Comment: for your clarification, I have done this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68083187/the-boolean-field-in-form-is-not-working-in-django

Comment: @santoshChauhan so it actually does work, despite you removing the accepted flag?! You're just not extracting the brands from the request in the view, I assume. Your related question can't be answered as it only includes the partial code that I wrote here as an example. There's more to do in the view than that.

Comment: What are more thing we have to do in view.py?

Comment: @santoshChauhan Well, you need to access the data passed by the form in `request.GET` and then do something with it. That's more inline with the way I started my answer where it accessed `brand = request.GET.get('brand')`. Now though, you'd need to check for the specific brands in the get parameters, or switch to a multiple choice question where you can just access `brand` as the named field and the brands might be the values of that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234107/discussion-between-santosh-chauhan-and-markwalker).